# VS 17 Loop Through Row, Call API, Injest JSON

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

**Goal:** I have a list of IDs in a MSSQL DB that I want to send to an API ([NPI Registry API](https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/help-api)) then parse the returned JSON to 
ingest certain elements back into the DB.

**Ask:** I am comfortable in t-sql inside of SSMS but very much a beginner anywhere outside, I'm hoping this exercise will be a good foray into using other web interfaces. *I don't want anyone to explain exactly how to do this but I was hoping someone could outline the most efficient route so I can tackle the rest myself*. I am hoping to do this through VS17 but am willing to go outside of VS if that's a better solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO, gmfredit.  What routes have you found so far?

Comment: 1. Read the rows (ADO.NET). 2. Do the API calls (HttpClient class). 3 parse the JSON (NewtonSoft.Json NuGet package). 4. Put the data in the database (again ADO.NET)

Comment: How are you getting the list of IDs?  Do you have any knowledge of EntityFramework?

Comment: @Ian - I'm so green that research alone has been a bit overwhelming, I was entertaining the idea of using Python but I think I should stick with VS since I have it available.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - excellent information, I'll concentrate my research in those areas.

Comment: @Neil - I'm getting the list of IDs by the 'Execute SQL' tool in VS, I don't have any knowledge of EntityFramework but I will research that as well. What does that provide that VS doesn't do?

Comment: EF is the defacto way of retrieving and storing data from any number of different SQL databases from dot net code.  There are ways to generate classes directly from the database (so you don't have to type it in yourself).  You have a lot of research to do.  Start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: FYI VS (Visual Studio) is an editor.  It allows you to edit code, but by the use of plugins, it will allow development using many different languages (C#/VB/F#/SQL etc etc etc).

Comment: @Neil, Ef is cool and easy but It can be easy to get in wrong with massive insert. those api call can give 200 results per call. I will recommend a buck insert, not Ef.

Comment: @DragandDrop The OP is a complete newbie to C#.  He should use the simplest and easiest way to complete a task until he is more familiar.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you should generally follow:

1. **Read the Rows**

   - Here you can use ADO.NET simple queries or any framework like Entity Framework or Dapper.NET
2. **Make your API calls**

   - Here you can use something like this.
   - It may vary a little bit depending on how you will use the IDs retrieved from the DB:

   :

   ```
   var companies = db.Companies.ToList(); //supposing db is you DbContext on EF
   var myTypesFromApi = new List<MyTypeT>();
   companies.ForEach(async company =>
   {
       try
       {
           using (var client = new HttpClient())
           {
               var res = await client.GetStringAsync("http://myapi.com/v1/");
               myTypesFromApi.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTypeT>(res));
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           //catch properly your exception here
       }
   });
   ```
3. **Send it back to the DB**

Comment: Does the 'Excecute SQL Task' that creates a list of NPI records I want to query the API for more detail on, meet step 1? Then I feed that item into a Script Task as a UserVariable?